# How to know if a switch is on/off in android Switch Preference

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

i want to know how can i know if the switch is on/off to perform an action depending on the state of the switch

```
enable_social_recommendations = (Preference)  findPreference("enable_social_recommendations");
enable_social_recommendations.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
@Override
public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {

    // here what should i do to know if the switch is on or off???

    return true;


}});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do the following:

```
@Override
public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
    if (newValue instanceof Boolean) {
        boolean isChecked = (boolean) newValue;
        // do whatever you want to do with this
    }
    return true;
}});
```

`instanceof Boolean` actually is not required, as `newValue` will be Boolean. But it is just to make sure that nothing bad can ever happen.

Comment: instanceOf is actually instanceof but thanks, it works!

Answer (score 0):

Use the newValue parameter that is passed to your changeListener.